# HTML - Position footer element in a table row with flexbox

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, position

I'm trying to bottom-align my element (`.table-footer`) inside in a table with flexbox. I would like table-footer to stick to the bottom of my `.table-row` like that:

[image]

I tried with:

```
.table-footer {
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0;
}

.table-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

But what I'm getting is:

[image]

I tried with position absolute and bottom 0 but it's not working well... can you advise me where is the problem? Thanks :)

You can try the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/a5dubgfj/

Comment: Why not just add another ```tr``` for the footer?

Comment: Hi, for web accesibility, they are a single row and each footer info are releated to each column

Comment: And if you stepped away from the whole ```table``` layout and designed it all with ```flex```?

Comment: Without the <table> event I have to implement manually all the ARIA roles... do you have a sample table in flex to use as example with this kind of footer in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
.table-footer {
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0;
}

.table-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 108px; //the height of the table row you have so far
}
```

there is probably better way of defining the height, but this worked for me

here's the the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8ubm96tk/

Comment: thanks! Do you have any suggestion on how to handle th dynamic height?

Comment: Depends on what your use case for this is. If you define the height of the parent div that this table will be in, then maybe make the height of the table and the table row 100%, that should work.